# How to shorten polyline for google static maps

Tags: python, c++, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I've got polylines too long for google static maps. The limit is about 8K, I need about 2.5K for style and other bits so about 5K is left for the path.
However, the biggest paths I've got are around 20K by themselves, AFAIK they come from the directions API.
How do I lower the level of detail in those paths to make the encoded data shorter?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm

Answer (score 0):

Looks like polyline is 10 characters long for lat/lon.  All you need to do is divide your 20K file into 4, if you want to "lower detail". I feel like you could do this pretty quickly with python.  Load up the string in a variable, and store chunks of 10 characters per 40. Then dump that into a file, and it should be 1/4 the size of the original 20K string, and you will lose 3/4 of you data points evenly.

Comment: Google polylines are delta encoded, so you can't simply remove pairs to shorten the line. You have to decode, edit, and then encode again.